# Nivo slider loading issue?

Tags: javascript, html, css, nivo-slider

Here's my [website](http://www.codtelevision.com). For some reason, my Nivo slider will not show up...it just sits there and loads. Why, and how do i fix it? Here is my CSS:

```
 #slider {
    position:relative;
    width:618px;
    height:246px;
    background:url(http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/images/loading.gif) no-repeat 50% 50%;
}
#slider img {
    display: none; 
    position:absolute;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
}

.nivo-controlNav {
    position:absolute;
    left:260px;
    bottom:-30px;
}
.nivo-controlNav a {
    display:block;
    width:22px;
    height:22px;
    background:url(http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/images/bullets.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
    margin-right:3px;
    float:left;
}
.nivo-controlNav a.active {
    background-position:0 -22px;
}

.nivo-directionNav a {
    display:block;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    background:url(http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/images/arrows.png) no-repeat;
    text-indent:-9999px;
    border:0;
}
a.nivo-nextNav {
    background-position:-30px 0;
    right:15px;
}
a.nivo-prevNav {
    left:15px;
}

.nivo-caption {
    text-shadow:none;
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
.nivo-caption a {
    color:#efe9d1;
    text-decoration:underline;
}

.clear {
    clear:both;
}
```

If that does not help, then look on my site or tell me what code to paste. Thanks!

Comment: Opening firebug in this site crashed my Mozilla. Cant look what is wrong. Aparently the Nivo is Loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the extra script tag in line 15 in html.

Update 1:

Change `$('#slider').nivoSlider();` to `$('#slider').nivoSlider({` so it will become as below.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices:15,
        animSpeed:600, //Slide transition speed
        pauseTime:8000,
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
        controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover:false, //Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, //Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, //Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} //Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

Update 2:

Okay, so you have a included a latest version of jQuery in your html in line 375. Please paste your Nivoslider after this line. Thats move the following script after line 375, say before the `</body>` tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/js/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

   $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices:15,
        animSpeed:600, //Slide transition speed
        pauseTime:8000,
        startSlide:0, //Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav:true, //Next & Prev
        directionNavHide:true, //Only show on hover
        controlNav:true, //1,2,3...
        controlNavThumbs:false, //Use thumbnails for Control Nav
        controlNavThumbsFromRel:false, //Use image rel for thumbs
        controlNavThumbsSearch: '.jpg', //Replace this with...
        controlNavThumbsReplace: '_thumb.jpg', //...this in thumb Image src
        keyboardNav:true, //Use left & right arrows
        pauseOnHover:false, //Stop animation while hovering
        manualAdvance:false, //Force manual transitions
        captionOpacity:0.8, //Universal caption opacity
        beforeChange: function(){},
        afterChange: function(){},
        slideshowEnd: function(){}, //Triggers after all slides have been shown
        lastSlide: function(){}, //Triggers when last slide is shown
        afterLoad: function(){} //Triggers when slider has loaded
    });
});
```

Update 3 :

OR you can include the latest version at the head and remove the conflict. So update the jquery including in the line 13 with the latest src `http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js` and change `$(window).load(function() {` in line 17 to `$(document).ready(function() {`. It will work.

Comment: Thanks about that, i fixed it, but it is still not loading

Comment: check my Update 1 in the above answer

Comment: Update 3 is the best approach

Comment: I can't see your site updated. Move the latest query including from line 374 to line 12 and change line 18 to `$('#slider').nivoSlider({` . It will work.

Comment: yeah, for got to change to (document) !

Comment: In your slider option change controlNav : false. It seems there is a typo there.

Answer (score 1):

ok first things first. Having looked at your code, there is a script tag at the top that isnt closed and doesnt contain anything. remove it.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#slider').nivoSlider();
    effect:'fade', //Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
    slices:15,
```

Edit: jQuery conflict.

At the top you have

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.codtelevision.com/nivo/js/jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script>
```

and at the bottom you have

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
```

Only include one version of jQuery on a page.

Comment: Thanks about that, i fixed it, but it is still not loading

Comment: in the tutorial, i am suposed to...http://serifaddons.com/nivo-slider-webplus.html

Comment: that tutorial doesnt tell u to include 2 different versions of jquery... you will never need to do that and never should because conflicts can occur. remove one and see what happens.

Comment: what on earth is your site trying to load? i've just looked at the amount of items it's trying to load and it's just continuously going up, currently on 8000 and still rising

Comment: oh...i have a timer to do a function every 5 seconds..should i take the timer off?

Comment: yea you should. i'll continue examing your code and see what i find.

Comment: i see this Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'nivoSlider'